# Characterization of continuity by subsequences.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

I have a difficulty trying to prove the following proposition. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

$\textbf{Prop.}$ Let $(X,d_1)$ and $(Y,d_2)$ be two metric spaces. A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous at $x_0\in X$ if and only if every sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ that converges to $x_0$ has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $f(x_{n_k})\rightarrow f(x_0)$.

The forwards direction is obvious using the usual sequential characterization of continuity.

For the reverse implication I tried arguing as follows: suppose, for contradiction, that $f$ is **not** continuous at $x_0$. Then there is some sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ that converges to $x_0$ but $(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does **not** converge to $f(x_0)$. I'm stuck here since I think $(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ may still have a subsequence that converges to $f(x_0)$, right?

Comment: You can do more: If $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$, there is an $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $(x_n)$ with limit $x_0$ such that $d_2\bigl( f(x_n), f(x_0)\bigr)\ge\epsilon$ for all $n$. (Note there's no need to argue by contradiction; just prove the contrapositive statement.)

Comment: Yes, $(f(x_n))$ can have subsequences converging to $x_0$. But under the assumption that $f(x_n) \not\to f(x_0)$, you can extract a subsequence such that ...

Comment: @DavidMitra Would proving the contrapositive mean that I must prove the following: If $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$ then there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $x_0$ that has no subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ satisfying $f(x_{n_k})\rightarrow f(x_0)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @DanielFischer We can extract a subsequence $(f(x_{n_k}))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that does not converge to $f(x_0)$. I'm still stuck I'm afraid.

Comment: You can extract a subsequence such that $\left(f(x_{n_k})\right)$ has no subsequence converging to $f(x_0)$. That is pretty much what David Mitra suggests.

Comment: @DavidMitra I think I'm finally seeing it. Did you write "for all $n$" in your first comment because we can remove a finite number of terms?

Comment: Note, by the definition of continuity (rather, its negation), if $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $\delta>0$, there is an $x_\delta$ with $d_1(x_\delta,x_0)<\delta$ and $d_2\bigl(f(x_\delta),f(x_0)\bigr)\ge\epsilon$. Use this to inductively construct the sequence mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: If you start with the sequence you already have, as Daniel suggests, you can find an $\alpha>0$ and a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$  so that $d_2\bigl(f(x_{n_k}), f(x_0)\bigr)\ge\alpha$ for all $k$. (Write down what it means for a sequence not to converge to a given point.)

Comment: Regards your previous comment. No, you may need to remove infinitely many terms (I may be misinterpreting what you're asking). I think it best to start from scratch using what I wrote in my third comment.

Comment: Thanks for all your helpful comments, I will try it in five minutes as I was out.

Comment: @DavidMitra Here goes: So we start with any sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x_0$. Now, since $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that $d_2(f(x_n),f(x_0))\geq \epsilon$ for all $x_n$ satisfying $d_1(x_n,x_0)<\delta(\epsilon)$. For each $m\in\mathbb{N}$ pick $x_{n_m}$ satisfying $d_1(x_{n_m},x_0)<\delta(m)$ but $d_2(f(x_{n_m}),f(x_0))\geq \epsilon$. Then $(x_{n_m})$ is a sequence converging to $x_0$ but $(f(x_{n_m}))$ has no subsequence converging to $f(x_0)$.

Comment: No, that's not right. Assume $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$. Then there *exists* an $\epsilon>0$ so that for *every* $\delta>0$, there is an $x_\delta$ ... So find (declare its existence) that *fixed* $\epsilon$. Let $\delta_1=1$. Choose $x_1$ so that $d(x_1,x_0)<\delta_1$ and $d(f(x_1),f(x_0))>\epsilon$. Then let $\delta_2=1/2$ and choose $x_2$ so that $d(x_2,x_0)<\delta_2$ and $d(f(x_2),f(x_0))>\epsilon$. Continue...

Comment: Ouch, that's a really bad mistake on my part. Sorry this is taking so long.

Comment: It might be instructive to consider  $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$, $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$. Here, $f$ is not continuous at $0$. Given any $\delta>0$, you can find $0<x<\delta$ such that $|f(x)|=1$. So you can construct a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $0$ such that $(f(x_n))$ is "bounded away from $f(0)$".

Comment: @DavidMitra I've finished it now. Thanks so much.